# Continue scrolling with flexslider

Tags: flexslider

I don't like when animationLoop is true that when it reaches the end of the slides, it does a quick scroll to the start. I would like it to instead keep a continues loop. I did NOT see an option for this so I am trying to keep adding the current slide to the end on the after callback, but it isn't working. Below is the code.

```
jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
    after: function(slider)
    {
        slider.addSlide(slider.slides[slider.currentSlide],slider.count-1);
    }
}
```